# how is this code on bs4 not work for all urls?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

i have made this code in python which works for when the url is https://www.fanfiction.net/anime/ but not when https://www.fanfiction.net/comics/ or https://www.fanfiction.net/misc/

the below code works fine for url of anime, book, cartoon, game, movie ,tv but not for comics, play or misc.

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

source = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.fanfiction.net/anime/").read()
print(source)
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
print(soup)
```

but when i change the url to comic, play or misc as below it return garbage values.

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

source = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.fanfiction.net/comic/").read()
print(source)
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
print(soup)
```

i thought the sever was timing me out so i used sleep function but then also it gave the error.
I have no idea what is causing or how to fix it. 
 Thanks for helping out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server is serving binary data to you (probably compressed). `requests` module will take care of this type of data automatically (instead of `urllib.request`):

```
import bs4 as bs
import requests

source = requests.get("https://www.fanfiction.net/comic/").text
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source,'lxml')
print(soup)
```

Prints:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta content="NOARCHIVE" name="ROBOTS"/>
<meta content="IE=edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible"/>
<meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection"/>
<meta content="app-id=1192753879" name="apple-itunes-app"/>

... and so on.
```